# git auto-merge does not work as expected

Tags: git, git-merge

I happen to have a file (say **abc**) in two branches: *master* and *sample*.

The commit date for **abc** on *sample* is older than **abc** on current *master*; in other words **abc** is latest on *master*.

Now, I ran:

```
git checkout sample
git merge master
```

It auto-merged several files (including **abc**).

Problem: Line#42 in **abc** seems to persist from branch *sample* instead getting replaced from *master*.

Why is this happening ? I was quite expecting otherwise. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that **abc** is newer on *master* than on *sample* doesn't means it gets wholly replaced by the *master* version during merge. If *sample*'s version of **abc** has some changes that are not present on *master*, even if they are older than the last change in *master*, git will try to preserve them during merge.

Comment: Is git merge not like a union of two versions of a file with conflicts raised  if there is an overlap in lines ? Why was there not a merge conflict in my case above ? It instead auto-merged .... @michael-ivko

Comment: @82Tuskers: If the three-way-merge of git was able to merge it properly, why should there be a merge conflict? Just be pleased that git was able to merge it without any problems. And if your master branch developed further and `sample` not, its even easier for git with a fast-forward merge.

Comment: @82Tuskers: merge does not form unions of *files*, but rather applies a union of *diffs* to a merge-base version of some file(s).  The merge-base is found by following commit history, after which git gets two diffs: base-vs-HEAD (and HEAD = tip of sample here) and base-vs-merge-version (master).  Git then combines the diffs.  If base-vs-HEAD changed line 42 but base-vs-master didn't, git keeps the change from HEAD (i.e., sample).  You get a conflict only when both sample and master changed line 42 (vs what was in base) *and* the two changes are *different*.

Comment: @torek I think this comment would be better as an answer.

Comment: I took @torek's lead and landed at [git-documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base). sample.abc and master.abc shared a merge-base (obviously) but #42 on sample.abc was the only one that changed since the common ancestor. Therefore, there was no conflict and git auto-merged sample.abc#42 over master.abc#42.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to keep in mind that, when merging, Git does not operate on the file level; rather, it operates on the *line* level. If a line was changed in `sample` but not in `master` (or in `master` but not in `sample`), that change will be in the merge of the two branches.

To see why Git does this, consider the following scenario:

1. `sample` is branched from `master`
2. Person X changes line 42 in ABC on `sample`
3. Person Y changes line 54 in ABC on `master`
4. The branches are merged

If Git merged the way you expected, then person X's changes would have been lost in this case. By checking line-by-line, Git preserves as many changes as possible. Note that if both person X and person Y had changed line 42, the merge would have resulted in a conflict, no matter what order the changes were made in.